# E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.example.honore.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble with searchable dictionary app that I imported from
Github; any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am able to start the app and type the word to be searched, however, no 
result is being displayed even when I type a word that I for sure is in the 
dictionary (definitions file). Also, the suggestion is not working. Please 
help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
package com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";


public static String AUTHORITY = 
"com.example.hodah1.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY 
+ "/dictionary");

// MIME types used for searching words or looking up a single definition
public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE =  
ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
"/vnd.example.hodah1.nativedictionary";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = 
ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
"/vnd.example.hodah1.nativedictionary";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

// UriMatcher stuff
private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();


/**
 * Builds up a UriMatcher for search suggestion and shortcut refresh 
   queries.
 */
private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // to get definitions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    // to get suggestions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, 
    SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
    SEARCH_SUGGEST);



    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, 
    REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT 
    + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;}


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}


@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String
[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {


// Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have and format the db 
query accordingly switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + 
                         uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}


private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
    /* SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                     (only if you want to refresh shortcuts) */
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};


    return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}


private Cursor search(String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};


    return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}


private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
    String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};


    return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}


private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {
           String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
            DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};


    return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}


@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}


// Other required implementations...


@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[]
selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}

package com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity{

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    handleIntent(getIntent());
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
handleIntent(intent);
}


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    }
    else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}


private void showResults(String query) 
{

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().quer
    (DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            new String[] {query}, null);


    if (cursor == null)
    {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] 
        {query}));
    }
    else
    {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString
        (R.plurals.search_results,
                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };


                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,R.id.definition };



        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.result, cursor, from, to, 1);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);


        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
        WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPa
                 (DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService
        (Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem
        (R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo
        (getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }


    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}


package com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


/**
 * The main activity for the dictionary.
 * Displays search results triggered by the search dialog and handles
 * actions from search suggestions.
 */
public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity{


private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    handleIntent(getIntent());
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
           handleIntent(intent);
}


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    }
    else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}


/**
 * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
 * @param query The search query
 */
private void showResults(String query) {


    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query
    (DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,new String[] {query}, null);


    if (cursor == null)
    {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] 
    {query}));
    }
    else
    {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString
(R.plurals.search_results,
                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);


        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

                    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                R.id.definition };

        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
R.layout.result, cursor, from, to, 1);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);


        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
position, long id) {
Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath
(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService
(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem
(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo
(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }


    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package = "com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
     <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_dictionary">


        <!-- The default activity of the app; displays search results. -->
         <activity android:name=".SearchableDictionary"
                   android:launchMode="singleTop">
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>

             <!-- Receives the search request. -->
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                          </intent-filter>


            <!-- Points to searchable meta data. -->
             <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />


         </activity>


         <!-- Displays the definition of a word. -->
         <activity android:name=".WordActivity" />


<provider android:name="com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider"

android:authorities="com.example.hodah01.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider"

android:enabled="true"
android:multiprocess="true"
android:exported="true" />

<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value=".SearchableDictionary" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Change the `authorities` attribute in the manifest's `<provider>` element to `"com.example.hodah1.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider"`.

Comment: Mike, I changed "authorities" attributes as you suggested, but still did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you rebuild the project? Depending on your IDE, changes in XML files might not trigger an automatic rebuild. Also, is your Provider class in the same folder as your Activities?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt it, and still gave me the same error. Yes, provider is in the same folder as the activity class.

Comment: Oh, yep, just saw that you included the package in that class. You might try changing the `name` attribute to the full path. I.e., `android:name="com.example.hodah1.nativedictionary.DictionaryProvider"`.

Comment: Mike, do you have email so that I can email you the project folder for you to look at? Thank you in advance for your help.